# How do I use javascript functions in html?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have been trying to use a function in a javascript file inside another html file. Essentially, it's not working and I think it has to do with my trying to make the javascript accessible on the html file. The function is supposed to add the values taken from the form and then output that sum. The first bit of code is my .js file and the second is my html.

```js
function reset()
{
 var q = new Array(5);
 
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  q[i] = 100;
 }
}

function calculate(form)
{
 var q = new Array(5);
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  q[i] = 100;
 }
 q[1] = document.worksheet1.Q1.options[document.worksheet1.Q1.selectedIndex].value;
 q[2] = document.worksheet1.Q2.options[document.worksheet1.Q2.selectedIndex].value;
 q[3] = document.worksheet1.Q3.options[document.worksheet1.Q3.selectedIndex].value;
 q[4] = document.worksheet1.Q4.options[document.worksheet1.Q4.selectedIndex].value;
 q[5] = document.worksheet1.Q5.options[document.worksheet1.Q5.selectedIndex].value;
 
 var total = (q[1]*1.0)+(q[2]*1.0)+(q[3]*1.0)+(q[4]*1.0)+(q[5]*1.0);
 
 document.worksheet1.totals.value = total;
}
```

```html
<html>

<header>
 <script language="Javascript" src="tmdcalculation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</header>

<body>
 <form name="worksheet1" id="worksheet1" onsubmit="calculate">
 <table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td><table>
    <tr>
     <td>Feeling</td>
     <td>How I have felt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Question 1?</td>
     <td><select name="Q1" size="1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Not at all</option>
      <option value="1">A Little</option>
      <option value="2">Moderately</option>
      <option value="3">Quite a Bit</option>
      <option value="4">Extremely</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Question 2?</td>
     <td><select name="Q2" size="1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Not at all</option>
      <option value="1">A Little</option>
      <option value="2">Moderately</option>
      <option value="3">Quite a Bit</option>
      <option value="4">Extremely</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Question 3?</td>
     <td><select name="Q3" size="1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Not at all</option>
      <option value="1">A Little</option>
      <option value="2">Moderately</option>
      <option value="3">Quite a Bit</option>
      <option value="4">Extremely</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Question 4?</td>
     <td><select name="Q4" size="1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Not at all</option>
      <option value="1">A Little</option>
      <option value="2">Moderately</option>
      <option value="3">Quite a Bit</option>
      <option value="4">Extremely</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Question 5?</td>
     <td><select name="Q5" size="1">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Not at all</option>
      <option value="1">A Little</option>
      <option value="2">Moderately</option>
      <option value="3">Quite a Bit</option>
      <option value="4">Extremely</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
   </table></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 <table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td><table>
    <tr>
     <td align="right"><input name="button" type="button" onclick="calculate(this.form)" value="Analyse" /></td>
     <td>Total Mood Calc: 
     <input name="totals" type="text" size="3" /></td>
     <td><input name="reset" type="reset" onclick="initial()" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

P.s Some extra questions. I had borrowed some of the code from a website because I am still quite new to both javascript and html. Why does the reset function have the array values all turned to 100? And, why doesn't the calculate function just call the reset function instead of doing the same thing?

Comment: the answer to "Why does the reset function have the array values all turned to 100?" is simple: `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) q[i] = 100;`

Comment: Still not working :/ but thanks for noticing that

Comment: no, it was just a comment to answer the most simple one of your questions, doesn't have to make anything work

Comment: @Shinratensei i know how the for loop works but i dont understand why its needed?

Comment: @Shinratensei yea the first comment was at someone who deleted their comment

Comment: And yes, the calculate function does the same as the reset function before calculating a new score, and it doesn't work because in the HTML you wrote `onclick="initial()"` instead of `onclick="reset()"`

Comment: it's not necessary at all, it doesn't have anything to change the text field like the `calculate()` function

Comment: @Shinratensei thanks for the help. Along with changing that I found 1 other mistake and now its working :)

Comment: great, make sure to revise your code more carefully next time

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a newbie to jscript and this may not work but can give this a go

```
function reset()
{
    var q = new Array(5);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        q[i] = 100;
    }
}

function calculate() {

    var q = new Array(5);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        q[i] = 100;
    }
    q[1] = document.worksheet1.Q1.options[document.worksheet1.Q1.selectedIndex].value;
    q[2] = document.worksheet1.Q2.options[document.worksheet1.Q2.selectedIndex].value;
    q[3] = document.worksheet1.Q3.options[document.worksheet1.Q3.selectedIndex].value;
    q[4] = document.worksheet1.Q4.options[document.worksheet1.Q4.selectedIndex].value;
    q[5] = document.worksheet1.Q5.options[document.worksheet1.Q5.selectedIndex].value;

    var total = (q[1]*1.0)+(q[2]*1.0)+(q[3]*1.0)+(q[4]*1.0)+(q[5]*1.0);

    document.worksheet1.totals.value = total;
}

<form name="worksheet1" id="worksheet1" onsubmit="return calculate()">
```